# Windows 10 - Remote Desktop- Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I am having a problem using remote desktop to work across 3 monitors.

My work set up is a desktop with 3 monitors (Windows 7 Pro).

I am going to be working remotely for a few weeks and would like to replicate this set up using my laptop (Asus S400CA / Windows 10 Enterprise) + 2 USB monitors (Lenovo ThinkVision LT1451).

Thus far, I have not been able to get this to work properly, or even get the RDU connection to span 2 screens while leaving the other screen powered on.

If I log into RD with both monitors configured, the RD only works on 1 screen.

If i disconnect 1 monitor (leaving laptop plus 1 monitor), the RD will display across 2 screens. Once I connect the 3rd screen, the RD connection contracts to only 1 screen.

I currently have the box checked to Use all monitors for the remote screen.
I have all set to the same resolution (1368 x 760). Relevant code is below.

use multimon:i:1
desktopwidth:i:1368
desktopheight:i:760
span monitors:i:3

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Terminals](https://terminals.codeplex.com/) to accomplish something similar. It's just a wrapper around the official Microsoft Terminal Services ActiveX Client (mstscax.dll) and has Fit To Window/Full Screen/AutoScale/Custom/Some Resolution That You Set options.

It will not give you *quite* what you are looking for if you have an asymetrical monitor setup.